# element for tomorrow CAML

Tags: caml-query, caml

I have a calendar and am wanting to find all the events that have been put into calendar for tomorrow. Is there an element like `<today/>` for tomorrow? 
Basically how can I get it so it only returns the events for tomorrow.
Here is my code, this returns the elements for today :

```
'<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
 <Value Type="DateTime"><Today /></Value></Eq></Where>
<OrderBy><FieldRef Name="EventDate" Ascending="FALSE"/></OrderBy></Query></View>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using  you want to use the Offset=""(or according to the comments on MSDN attribute should be OffsetDays="") on the Element

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
                <Value Type="DateTime"><Today OffsetDays="+1"/></Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="EventDate" Ascending="FALSE"/>
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
</View>
```

Edit adding link to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms460496(v=office.14).aspx